# JQuery DELETE Ajax request does what it has to but then raises error

Tags: jquery, ajax, http

Something is wrong with my AJAX request.

```
$.ajax({
    type : "DELETE",
    url : deleteUrl,        
    success : function(result) {
        alert("Done!");
    },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Fail!");
    }
});
```

This request accomplishes its work on the server-side, but then it goes to the 'error: ' part of the code instead of 'success: '. The reason is "400 bad request". Please, let me know if you have any suggestions how to fix it.

Comment: The reason for this is due to your server code returning a `400` status code. The `success` handler only fires when a `200 OK` response is received.

Comment: what is the "deleteurl" ? just run the same url in an another tab and see what output you get.

Comment: try adding a proper `contentType` to your ajax code like `contentType:"application/json; charset-utf8;"`

Comment: var deleteUrl =  "/articles?a=" + articleId . I guess it can not be wrong because my server processes it correctly.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks! I'll try to find a reason on the server-side.

Comment: @BhaveshGangani Testing like that won't work. Browsers send GET requests, whereas this is explicitly sending a DELETE.